# MAGMA: semidirect product of finite matrix group in matrix form

Tags: group-theory, semidirect-product, magma-cas

Apologies for the very novice question. I am trying to find conjugacy classes and representatives (in matrix form) of a finite group of matrices $G$, isomorphic to $$ (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^3 \rtimes S_3. $$
The isomorphism is as follows: the $i$-th copy of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is generated by the diagonal matrix with entries $\omega = e^\frac{2\pi \sqrt{-1}}{n}$ in the $(i,i)$ entry, and 1 elsewhere, and $S_3$ acts by conjugation, permuting the copies of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

I set this problem up in Magma using `SemidirectProduct` (an example follows with $n=3$).
The command `Classes(G);` seems to be what I want, however, it returns representatives expressed in cycle notation since `SemidirectProduct` presents $G$ as a permutation group. Is there a way to preserve the matrix form of the elements of the group when invoking `SemidirectProduct` (getting elements of the semidirect product as pairs of matrices)? Or an alternative way to construct the group $G$?

```
//Three copies of Cyclic group
F<w> := CyclotomicField(3);
H := MatrixGroup< 3, F | [w,0,0, 0,1,0, 0,0,1], [1,0,0, 0,w,0, 0,0,1], [1,0,0, 0,1,0, 0,0,w] >;

//Permutation group
K := MatrixGroup<3, F | [0,1,0, 1,0,0, 0,0,1], [0,0,1, 1,0,0, 0,1,0]>;
k1 := elt <K | 0,1,0, 1,0,0, 0,0,1>;
k2 := elt  <K | 0,0,1, 1,0,0, 0,1,0>;

//Conjugacy action
A := AutomorphismGroup(H);
p1 := elt<A|hom<H->H | g :-> g^k1>>;
p2 := elt<A|hom<H->H | g :-> g^k2>>;
f := hom<K->A| k1 -> p1, k2-> p2>;

G := SemidirectProduct(H,K,f);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SemidirectProduct` intrinsic actually produces several maps as output that you can use for this.  For example we can define

```
G, m1, m2, m3 := SemidirectProduct(H,K,f);
```

Then we have that

1. $m_{1} : H \to G$ by $h \mapsto (h,1)$,
2. $m_{2} : K \to G$ by $k \mapsto (1,k)$ (here of course the outputs of $m_{1}$ and $m_{2}$ are actually permutations in $G$ corresponding to these matrix pairs),
3. $m_{3} : G \to K$ by $g \mapsto k$ where $g = m_1(h)*m_2(k)$.

This give a nice way to take a matrix pair $(h,k) : h \in H, k \in K$ as an element of $G$ by

```
g := m1(h)*m2(k)
```

(I know you are asking about the other direction).

If you would like to turn a permutation in $G$ to a pair of matrices $(h,k)$, we can write a function

```
function PermutationToMatrixPair(g)
    k := m3(g);
    h := (m1^-1)(g*m2(k^-1));
    return <h,k>;
end function;
```

This will take $g$ as a permutation, and you want to write it as a corresponding ordered pair of matrices $h \in H$, $k \in K$;

- $k$ we can get directly from the projection map $m_{3}$, `k := m3(g)`.
- Then if we multiply $g$ by (the permutation corresponding to)
  $k^{-1}$, we have a new permutation $g^{\prime}$ that corresponds to
  $(h,1)$; ie `gprime := g*m2(k^-1)`;
- to recover the matrix $h$ from the permutation, we can take the
  inverse image under our embedding map $m_{1}$ (since this map has as
  its image the set of permutations in $G$ corresponding to matrix
  pairs of the form $(h,1)$ with $h \in H$); `h := (m1^-1)(gprime)`.

(Note: you will either need to define this function at an appropriate place in your code where `m1`, `m2`, `m3` have been previously defined, or else define the function as taking `m1`, `m2`, `m3` as arguments.)

As an alternate way to do this, you can define a map with specified inverse to convert back and forth between permutations and matrix pairs.

```
phi := map<G-> CartesianProduct(H,K) | g  :-> <(m1^-1)(g*m2(m3(g)^-1)), m3(g)>,
                                       hk :-> m1(hk)*m2(hk) >;
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try right away